# Is there a way to have Google Calendar scroll to normal hours by default?

Tags: google-calendar

When I open up a day in day view for Google Calendar, it starts at 12AM, which means I can't see any of the real stuff in the day until I scroll down. Is there any way to make it auto scroll or just offset the day somehow so the normal "awake" hours are shown?

Comment: Actually it does not always jump to 12AM.
It jumps to the current time, which I think is a good behaviour.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Effective October 2011, there is a feature in Google Calendar Labs called "Hide morning and night" which lets you minimize the wee hours of the morning and the late hours of the evening if you never have much of anything in them.

Click on the "Settings" gear, then "Labs" and enable "Hide morning and night".  When you save it, you'll get additional options in your settings to specify what hours should be considered "night."

Answer (score 1):

Nope, not according to Google Calendar settings.

There could be a way to manipulate the page through some **Greasmonkey** scripting, but as to the code for it, it would be better suited for Stack Overflow.

Comment: No if somebody could find this script :)